# Toolbar title not aligned to the center when there's a navigation icon

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

I have a custom toolbar in which I set the title and other things programatically. The thing is, even though the title has the setting gravity="center", whenever the navigationIcon appears, it is moved a little bit to the side (like in the picture).

I understand that since the icon is not in the xml it must be moving it but is there a way to make the textView stay in the center no matter the icons? Or is there a way to add an ImageView or Button to the xml and then set the navigationIcon to that button so that the icon is contemplated in the code?

[image]

This is my xml, I added the buttons but I don't know a way to set the icons programatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:id="@+id/constraintly"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="41dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_gravity="center">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/navigationIcon"
           android:layout_width="24dp"
           android:layout_height="24dp"
           android:scaleType="center"
           android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/title"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           style="@style/NavBar.Title"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:ellipsize="end"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           tools:text="Title"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/subtitle"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:ellipsize="end"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
           style="@style/NavBar.SubTitle"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/centeredTitleTextView"
           tools:text="Subtitle"/>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/closeIcon"
           android:layout_width="24dp"
           android:layout_height="24dp"
           android:scaleType="center"
           android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is the part where the navigationIcon is set but setNavigationIcon cannot take the view.

```
   public void setNavigationIconArrow() {
       super.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_ui_24dp);
   }

   public void setNavigationIconClose() {
       super.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_24dp);
   }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the icon size, your layout starts after that. So you can't use gravity=center. Also, You can't set static left margin or right margin, Because, Android has so much different screen sizes. So you have to do this programmatically.

1- You have to find the phone's screen width size.

2- Convert that size px to dp.

3- Now you can set the left margin to your layout. Which you want in gravity=center.

I hope, I did help you what you want:)

Comment: I understand, but if the margin I need is 12 since the text can be long/short, so how can I set the gravity after getting the width? constraint layout does not seem to allow setting its gravity programmatically